# Element with position:absolute inside another positioned element doesn't inherit background color

Tags: css, css-position

It's known that unless an element with position:absolute isn't inside another positioned element, it will be out of flow. Therefore span doesn't have blue background.

```
<body>
  <div class = "main" style="background-color: blue;" />
      <span style="position:absolute"> Some content right here</span>
  </div>
  </body>
```

However if we put `position:relative` to .main's style, span should have blue background. So why doesn't it?

Comment: First of all your code isn't valid and if you give some width and height to div then it'll work too - https://jsfiddle.net/oe4Ln5y3/

Comment: Because span has absolute position, the main div has no content. If you set spans position to relative it will work. It will also work if you set width and height to the div as mentioned in aboves comment.

Comment: @Anonymous My question wasn't about how to make it work, but rather why it doesn't work in this particular example. I got the answer below. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Background color**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) isn't inherited (although it can be made to) regardless of positioning so it's not clear what you are asking.

However, in this instance, because you have positioned the child div absolutely the parent collapses (as the child is now out of the flow) to no height and so shows no background.

If you give the div some height, the background will appear. This, however, will not affect the background of the span, which defaults to *transparent*.